# Add custom filed to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to add a custom field to my Wordpress page but it's not working. When I set its value nothing happens on the HTML.

I read the Wordpress documentation and I tried to follow the steps there but something went wrong. 
Everything else it's working, like the_title(), the_post_thumbnail()...it's just this custom field that I it's not Working :(

https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Custom Field:

[image: Custom Field:]

Functions.php

```
$supports = array (

'title',
'editor',
'thumbnail',
'custom-fields'

);
```

HTML

```
<?php  

     $args = array ('post_type' => 'produtos');
          $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                  if ($loop->have_posts() ) {
                          while ($loop->have_posts() ) {
                            $loop->the_post();
                          ?>

    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-12">
        <div class="produtos-head">
            <div class="img-fluid produtos-img">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();  ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="produtos-titulo d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <?php the_title(); ?>

        </div>
        <div class="preco-original"> Price:R$
            <?php $original_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'original_price', true);
                                                if($original_price){ ?>
                <p>
                    <? echo $original_price; ?>
                </p>
                <?php 

  }else{ 

  }
?>
        </div>
        <div class="preco-promocional"> <span> Sale: </span>
            <span class="preco-promocional-number"> $ </span>

        </div>
        <button class="btn-vendedor"> Contact </button>
    </div>

    <?php
                }
              }
               ?>

        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID` and need to change `<? echo $original_price; ?>` to `<?php echo $original_price; ?>`

Comment: `<? echo` to `<?php echo` is not needed but recommended.